# Force the iOS device to change orientation

Tags: ios, orientation

First of all, I would like to apologize for asking the same question again which has been asked in this forum many times. But, my problem is that I've tried all the suggested solutions but still I haven't got a solution to my problem.

I have a `ViewControllerA` in Potrait mode and `ViewControllerB` in landscape mode. When the device changes from potrait to landscape, i can see `ViewControllerB` opening in landscape mode, but when the device is rotated back to potrait mode, `ViewControllerA` is displayed but still in landscape mode. Could anybody help me understand how can I display it back in potrait mode?

I have tried following things but nothing worked for me:

Added following code in `ViewControllerA` in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Have also added following functions in this view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you by using supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow

**Appdelegate.h**

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

in **Appdelegate.m**

```
  -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    //restrictRotation is BOOL value
     if(self.restrictRotation)//set the bool value to view controller which you want to load in landscape
          return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
     else
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**//call this where you need**

**requiredViewController.m**

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{

  appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

//In ViewdidLoad()

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self restrictRotation:YES];//Set YES if required in Landscape mode
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i already have this in the appdelegate. instead of  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll I have defined UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion solved my issue. i just realised that I'm not setting the BOOL variable (isVideoView in my case) to NO before moving from ViewControllerB to ViewControllerA. Now i can see the  ViewControllerA in potrait mode but the only problem is that its not perfect in the sense the imageview seems to be distorted. Do you have any idea?

Comment: STILL NOT WORKING. WHAT SHOULD I MODIFY FOR PINFO.LIST ?

Comment: @raju gujarati I have used this in my app..It is working correctly for me.. In  info.list I have set supported orientation to LandscapeRight and Landscape left..If any issues let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I placed it in viewWillAppear, but no use ..:(

Comment: Please try to put it in viewWillDisappear in ViewControllerB.  I am assuming you are opening ViewControllerA after ViewControllerB.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

& also in viewWIllAppear write

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"]
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation did the trick but since I'm calling this in viewDidAppear, so there is a delay in moving from landscape to potrait, I can see the view in landscape mode and then it rotates back to potrait. But i want that it should instantly move to potrait mode. I was not aware of this though. Thanks once again!

Comment: please vote it or accept the answer.If it helped you.

Comment: there's another answer which solved my issue completely, unfortunately there's no way to vote for both!