# How to restrict rotation of view controller in ios 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to disable the autorotation of iOS device for few view controllers.Like i have one few controller i want it to be displayed only in portrait mode.Where as others view controller in landscape mode.I have used following code but these delegate methods are never called?

```
#pragma mark Orientation handling

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return  (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158690/force-the-ios-device-to-change-orientation/31158872#31158872

Comment: Are you inside a navigation controller?
If so, you should override thoses methods in your navigation controller.

Comment: I am not inside navigation controller

Comment: Those *aren't* delegate messages. Which class have you put them into and what's your complete view controller hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

I used following method to forcefully set portrait orientation only for some selected view and its work for me, may be it will be help you

**1, Create one global flag**

Create on Global flag in your AppDelegate Method So you can access it in any View controllers .

In your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (assign) BOOL flagOrientationAll;
```

In your AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize flagOrientationAll;
```

Add following method in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if(flagOrientationAll == YES){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;  // All orientation support
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;   // Set only one orientation you want 
    }
}
```

**2, Add following code in ViewController .m for that you want to restrict rotation**

```
// set flag "flagOrientationAll" to rotate only one view in your particular view 

#import AppDelegate.h
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog (@"webViewController -- viewWillAppear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.flagOrientationAll = NO;
}
```

Here my POST : [How to set one of the screens in landscape mode in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422373/how-to-set-one-of-the-screens-in-landscape-mode-in-iphone/19423135#19423135)

If you get any trouble let me know!!